# How to get Drawing fill color using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, drawing, epplus, shapes

I am trying to figure out how to get Fill color from an ExcelDrawing. There are simple arrows in excel file.

I've tried casting the ExcelDrawing to ExcelShape which has the fill color and style properties, which would be perfect but the cast results in null. I've tried numerous google searches, though it was in vain. Most of the result regarding ExcelShape were how to CREATE one, not to read.

Not sure if this helps but that's what I've tried:

```cs
var drawings = worksheet.Drawings;
var drawing = drawings.First(/*that matches the condition*/);
var castDrawing = drawing  as ExcelShape; //this results in null even though the drawing exists
```

**EDIT:** in excel drawn arrows are of Line type (from Shapes -> Lines). Any other shape is recognized when cast to ExcelShape.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the UnitTest of EPPlus about Drawings.

https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlusTest/DrawingTest.cs

These tests give a good glimpse on all properties usable.

Not really sure if First is implemented correctly on the Drawings collection, as it might be a Library Object.

You might want to try :
(worksheet.Drawings["shape1"] as ExcelShape).Fill.Color;

Where you use the names you gave to the Shapes in your code.

Comment: I've looked at the tests. If you look at my edit I mostly figured out what was the issue. But since the user uses Lines instead of other shapes Epplus cannot recognize them fully. Not sure why.